# Using multiple artboards in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I've got a fairly large illustrator work document where I've been mocking up and developing a logo over time. Each 'stage' is presented on it's own artboard to separate it from the previous.

I'm about ready to send this to the client now, but can I export the separate artboards into a paged PDF. What are my options with regard to exporting from this setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just Save-as PDF.  Artboards will turn into pages...

Comment: "Use Artboards" is on by default and can't be unchecked for PDF. The default is "All."

Answer (score 2):

Exporting the individual pages as pdfs and turning them into a 'binder' using Adobe Acrobat would do the trick. That's how I go about things with Illustrator CS anyway, not sure if later versions have more facility to do this without exporting.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting as a PDF will treat your artboards as pages, as will exporting to any other format (such as JPEG -- individual image files) as long as you have the Clip to Artboard box checked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Adobe Illustrator CS5 Edition. I was having the same problem as you but this is what I did:

Go to:
`File→Scripts→SaveDocsAsPDF ...`→ Choose your folder and then click → **OK**.

Adobe Illustrator will save the open documents one by one in the PDF Format.
Maybe you can use another software like Nitro PDF to combine these PDF documents 
into one.
Hope this helps a bit but I would be happy to know a shorter method to combine these PDF's into one using illustrator only.

Thanks.
Misheck

Answer (score -1):

Rather than saving as PDF, print to the "Adobe PDF" or "Adobe PDF Converter". This will produce a single PDF document with each artboard as a page.